# 30a outdoor generator inlet box to transfer switch

Tags: electrical, generator, transfer-switch

I have a 8K watt running (10k peak) tri fuel generator with a cord to a 30a inlet box, which is on the exterior of my home.

Can I run a single 35ft run of UF 10/3 straight from my inlet box to the transfer switch? It is not in an area subject to damage. Also, whats the best way to feed the UF through the exterior wall into a basement?

It will have to run about 2 feet exposed on the exterior from the box to the closest point I could enter (thats why Im using UF). Unfortunately the box cannot be moved in front of the entry point due to an outdoor kitchen/bar that cant be moved and doesn't have the space behind it to run conduit.

Comment: 30A is 7200W, so you really need a 40/50A inlet and breaker.

Comment: Mike, please [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: Based on your statement about behind a kitchen in the deleted “answer”, I may follow better now the area is enclosed with cabinetry in that if it is truly not accessible UF would work, if the UF could be accessed inside a cabinet metal clad may be needed if pipe would not be possible. I did not follow at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this size generator comes with a 240v 30 amp twist lock if you are using this your 10-3 with ground is the appropriate size but that first 2’ that is exposed needs protection putting the UF in conduit will do the job. Most jobs like this come out of the box with pvc go to an lb conduit fittings then into the home. A one or two hole strap on the conduit is required. Just calk around the pipe to seal the hole. Once inside run the UF like normal NM (Romex) or switch to standard NM at a junction box.